# Neo4j : Replace Existing Node

Tags: c#, neo4j, merge, graph-databases, neo4jclient

I'm trying to use Neo4JClient to replace an existing node. I'm still rather fresh with Neo4j so i'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. The query should update all the properties on the existing node to those of the new node.

```
    public static Node<VitalSignEvent> MergeVitalSignEvent(VitalSignEvent mergedEvent)
    {

        try
        {
            vsNode = DBUtils.DBService.Cypher
                .Merge($"(evt:VitalSignEvent {{ItemId: {mergedEvent.ItemId}, DateObserved: {mergedEvent.DateObserved} }})")
                .OnMatch()
                .Set("evt = merged")
                .WithParam("merged", mergedEvent)
                .Return(evt => evt.As<Node<VitalSignEvent>>())
                .Results.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(nameof(MergeVitalSignEvent), e);
        }
        return vsNode;
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Can you provide more detail? Your code will create a new node only if an existing node with the same pattern does not already exist, and it returns either the first existing matching node or the new node. Neither "updates" nor "replacements" are done.

Comment: @cybersam Want it to update the existing node. If any property is different it should get the values of the new node.

Comment: But there is no "new" node yet. Are you trying to create a new node if a matching node does not yet exist? And do you want to use `mergedEvent.ItemId` as the "key" for finding the existing node, or do you want to use `mergedEvent.ItemId` and `mergedEvent.DateObserved` together as the key?

Comment: @cybersam I've updated the question with the full method

Comment: Can you answer my last questions?

Comment: @cybersam If no existing event is found it should create a new one. The key is a combination of `mergedEvent.ItemId` and `mergedEvent. DateObserved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `OnMatch()` call, since you want to set the properties on newly created nodes as well as existing nodes.

```
        vsNode = DBUtils.DBService.Cypher
            .Merge($"(evt:VitalSignEvent {{ItemId: {mergedEvent.ItemId}, DateObserved: {mergedEvent.DateObserved} }})")
            .Set("evt = $merged")
            .WithParam("merged", mergedEvent)
            .Return(evt => evt.As<Node<VitalSignEvent>>())
            .Results.FirstOrDefault();
```